# delete all row in table using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to delete table urls after confirmation using ajax and php, but it is deleting without any confirmation.

Here's my code:

```html
<form action="admin.php" method="post">
<button type="submit" id="deleteall" name="deleteall" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
<?php
  include 'db.php';

  if(isset($_POST["deleteall"])){

  $req="DELETE FROM `urls` WHERE 1";
  $conn->exec($req);

  $conn==null;
  }
  ?>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
//delea all

 $(document).on('click', '.deleteall', function(){
  var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"admin.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:user_id,

   });
  }
  else
  {
   return false; 
  }
 });


});
```

Comment: `$req="DELETE FROM \`urls\` WHERE 1";` ?  You need a column. WHERE id=1 ex

Comment: Your architecture is too far from my ideals (and comprehension), but I can say that you need to set `$_POST['deleteall']` somewhere in your ajax. You're only posting an user_id, but no parameter named "deleteall" on your request body.

Comment: @Felype im using pdo in db and one single page admin.php im just want to delete all row in table urls but after confirmation i think thats clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the params as object :

```
$.ajax({
    url:"admin.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: {user_id: user_id, deleteall: true},
    ...
});
```

Then in your `admin.php` add the passed `user_id` to the query :

```
if( isset($_POST["deleteall"]) && isset($_POST["user_id"]) ){

    $req="DELETE FROM `urls` WHERE id=".$_POST["user_id"];
    $conn->exec($req);
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are different way for do that... this is one:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?") == true) {
        // here ajax
    } 
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="confirmFunction()">Delete</a>
```

**Please pay attention** that your query will be remove everything from all users

Comment: yes,, i know about this it's work but i would using ajax to return message : records is deleted